# Tag deletion system

Tags: feature-request, tags, flags

I've encountered many tags which should not exist. (Too localized, dependent on other tags etc). I suggest a system that would allow the deletion of those tags (without having to post a question here on meta for each one).

A simple 'flag' option on tags should be good, so that a moderator can safely remove it, or even add it as a privilege and allow users to cast delete votes on tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far, posting questions on meta seems to be working fine... what do you take issue with in regards to the current system?

By posting a question on meta, there is a **public** history of *who* asked for the tag to be deleted, *how many users agree* via upvotes, and a *discussion* on the topic via answers / comments.

What you're proposing would hide all that from public view and make it more of a behind-closed-doors moderators only activity.

Right now anyone can (fairly easily) see a list of all tag synonym activity on meta:

- [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms)
- [ambiguous-tags](/questions/tagged/ambiguous-tags)
- [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request)
- [tag-blacklist-request](/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist-request)
- [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)

By taking this activity away from the community, you end up with more work for the mods, less input from the community, less accountability, and more secrecy.

What's the benefit in this?

Comment: Point taken. I wanted to have a more organized system and not "litter" the meta with such requests, but if the community prefers it this way, so be it :)

Comment: I think the -3 on your question means they do prefer it this way... Now, if you asked a question proposing a standard tag to use here on MSO (instead of the mess of tags I have in my answer) I would upvote that and I suspect many others would, too! That would be clean and still open.